# bmp280 temperature compensation calculation wrong in datasheet

Tags: integer, algebra, datasheet

I'm working on a project that uses a BMP280 sensor. The raw temperature / pressure values have to be compensated using calibration values stored in the device. This is now about the **temperature** compensation calculation, more precisely about the integer algebra version of it published in the [datasheet](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bmp280-ds001.pdf).

We are on page 22/23. The calculation of var1 is:

`var1 = (adc / 16384 - t1 / 1024) * t2`

which according to the datasheet in 32 bit systems (assuming 32 bit signed integer **variables** and adc as a 20 bit unsigned **value**, t1 and t2 are as 16 bit signed **values**):

`var1 = [(adc>>3 - t1<<1) * t2]>>11`

The trick is that adc is a 20 bit unsigned value. I think it's wrong because multiplying a 20 bit value right shifted 3 (yields a 17 bit value) with a 16 signed is 33 bit data with the sign bit. The maximum value for adc ic 0xFFFFF shifted -> 1FFFF * 7FFF = FFFD8001. The max value of a signed 32 int is 7FFFFFFF. It will overflow at high temperatures. (What a lovely way to fail)

I think the correct calculation would be:

`var1 = [(adc>>4 - t1) * t2]>>10`

PS: the datasheed does say to use these calculations at your own risks but it doesn't make this any better.

Any comments on this?

Edit: yes, there is the -t1 part that could in theory knock down a bit from the adc value. But t1 can be very little, even zero, counting on this to knock down another bit worth of value is wishful thinking.